# Get selected item

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I want to dynamically populate an array and get all values from the selected items. For example, I have an array of two objects:

```js
var allAdds = new Object();

var first = new Object();
first.ID = 1;
first.Location = "London";
first.Title = "some lovely title";
first.Description = "nice and long description";
first.DueDate = "2020-01-25";

var second = new Object();
second.ID = 2;
second.Location = "Manchester";
second.Title = "some lovely title";
second.Description = "nice and long description";
second.DueDate = "2020-01-23";

allAdds = [first, second];
var myString = JSON.stringify(allAdds);
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(myString);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
    <div class="list-group" id="myAddList"></div>
    <button type="button" id="add" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> add</button>
  </div>
```

I managed to add them dynamically to my html:

```js
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  $('#myAddList').append(
    '<div>' +
    '<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">' +
    '<div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">' +
    '<h5 class="mb-1">' + value.Title + '</h5>' +
    '<small>' + value.DueDate + '</small>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<p class="mb-1">' + value.Description + '</p>' +
    '<small>' + value.Location + '</small>' +
    '</a></div>'
  );
});
```

However, What I would like to achieve is to extract selected object. i.e., If I press on the first item, I would like to receive it as an object for the further manipulation.

How I get selected item:

```js
$(".list-group div").click(function(e) {
    $(".list-group .list-group-item").removeClass("active");
    $(e.target).addClass("active");
```

### EDIT

What I would like to have:

```
var selectedItem = new Object();
selectedItem.ID = ???;
selectedItem.Title = ???;
selectedItem.Location = ???;
```

and so on. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: How do you select an item?

Comment: It adds "Active" class to the selected item. However, I would like to get all object from it. And this is where I got stuck

$(".list-group div").click(function(e) {
        $(".list-group .list-group-item").removeClass("active");
        $(e.target).addClass("active");

Comment: Can you edit the question to include that? Also it seems from that line of code, all you need to do to get the selected items is `$('.active')`? Potentially using `map()` as well if you want to build an array of their attributes/properties.

Comment: Question is very confusing. Please explain it futher and include all needed code if you seek help.

Comment: you do this json parsing as an example to "fake" the actual request?

Comment: @johnSmith Yes, it is fake request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume variable `data` is globally defined, if not temporarly store it into whatever variable, then you could make a "get-function"

```
  function getDataById(id){
      var __found = jQuery.grep(data, function( n, i ) {return id == n.id;});       
      return __found[0];
  }
```

in your "generated markup" you add a data attribute containing the id

```
 '<div data-id="'+value.ID+'" > ... </div>'
```

and in your click-handler you can use the function now

```
$(".list-group div").click(function(e) {
   var selectedItem = getDataById($(this).attr('data-id'));
   console.log(selectedItem.Title);
   ...
```

dont know if i understood your questioncorrectly though

Comment: Thank you! Working as expected!

Answer (score 1):

Visit on the fiddle link I have added a sample for same

$(".list-group div").click(function(e) {

```
$(".list-group .list-group-item").removeClass("active");
$(e.target).addClass("active");
console.log($(this).attr('data-id'));
console.log($(this).attr('data-title'));
console.log($(this).attr('data-location'));
```

});

https://jsfiddle.net/prashantchaurasia/c9251udL/1/

Comment: Thnak you! both yours and accepted answer author solutions working as exptected!